# Searchview with recyclerview and cursor

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite, searchview

I am using recyclerview with sqlite database. Now I want to add searchview functionality.

I want to filter recylerview with cursor directly. I saw many post of this site but people use arrays.

I read about it and better solution is to read data from cursor and then use cursorAdapter then update screen. (Not read data from cursor next write it to array, then use array adapter and prints it on screen).

If I understood it properly. Searchview use cursor then fill an array then prints results of it on screen.

So it is possible to use searchview without using an array?

I should extend my adapter with filterable or use textwatcher in Mainactivity?

Can somebody explain me those things?

**EDIT**

My code:

`Edit_delete_product`:

```
public class Edit_Delete_Product extends AppCompatActivity implements DataBase_helper_interface {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private Recycler_Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    DataBase_Helper myDatabase;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    public Cursor cursor3;
    long cursor_pos;
    Intent next_activity;
    SearchView searchView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit__delete__product);
        myDatabase = new DataBase_Helper(this);
        db = myDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
        build_RecyclerView();


        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                // Some solutions I tried
                // 1
               mAdapter = new Recycler_Adapter(getApplicationContext(),cursor1);
               mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //2
                mAdapter.swapCursor(searchdata(newText));
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                // searchdata(newText);
                Log.i("Tag2", String.valueOf(searchdata(newText)));
                //3
                mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                //return false;
                //4
                mAdapter.filter(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });
        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new Recycler_Adapter.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View itemview) {
                cursor_pos = (long) itemview.getTag();
                next_activity = new Intent(itemview.getContext(), Product_specific_detail.class);
                next_activity.putExtra("key", cursor_pos);
                startActivity(next_activity);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        mAdapter.swapCursor(getAllItems());
    }

    public void build_RecyclerView(){
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_edit_del_product);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        mAdapter = new Recycler_Adapter(this, getAllItems());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.search_view_edit_delete_product);
    }

    private Cursor getAllItems() {
        return db.query(Table_Name,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }

    private Cursor searchdata(String text) {

        //1 solution
    /*    return db.query(Table_Name, null, NAME_PRODUCT, new String[]{text}, null, null, null);
    }*/
        //2
          cursor1 =  db.query( Table_Name, new String[] { NAME_PRODUCT}, NAME_PRODUCT + " LIKE ?",
                new String[] { text }, null, null, null,
                null);
        if(cursor1 != null){
            cursor1.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor1;
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class Recycler_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Recycler_Adapter.recyclerViewHolder> implements DataBase_helper_interface, Filterable {
    private Context context;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private ClickListener clickListener;
    ArrayList<Cursor> awad = new ArrayList<>();
    String product_name;
    long id;

    public interface ClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View itemview);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(ClickListener mclickListener) {
        clickListener = mclickListener;

    }

    public static class recyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView mImageView1;
        public TextView mTextView1;

        public recyclerViewHolder(final View itemView, final ClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rec_image);
            mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rec_text_1);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        int position = getLayoutPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onItemClick(itemView);


                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
    public Recycler_Adapter(Context mConext, Cursor mCursor) {
        context = mConext;
        cursor = mCursor;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public recyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_template, parent, false);
        recyclerViewHolder recViewHold = new recyclerViewHolder(v, clickListener);
        return recViewHold;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull recyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (!cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            return;
        }
        product_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NAME_PRODUCT));
        holder.mTextView1.setText(product_name);
        id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID));
        holder.itemView.setTag(id);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    public void swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        cursor = newCursor;
        if (newCursor != null) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public void filter(String text) {
        //    unfortunately delete content from here. Maybe here I should have filter method without implementing filterable?
    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return simpleFilter;
    }

    private Filter simpleFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            if (product_name.toLowerCase().trim().contains(constraint)) {
                for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    awad.add(cursor);
                    //I thought about adding "matching" cursors to array and show this array in recycclerview or if
                    // it is empty show all data like at the beginning.
                }

            }
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = awad;
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            awad.clear();
            awad.addAll((ArrayList) results.values);
            Log.i("TAG", product_name);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

}


}
```

DataBase Helper:

```
public class DataBase_Helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements DataBase_helper_interface {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    DataBase_Helper myDatabase;
    Cursor cursor;
    public DataBase_Helper(Context context) {
        super(context, Data_Base_Name, null, Data_Base_Version);
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + Table_Name + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + DataBase_helper_interface.NAME_PRODUCT + " TEXT);";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table_Name);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

Interface:

```
public interface DataBase_helper_interface extends BaseColumns {
    public static final String Data_Base_Name = "database_name";
    public static final int Data_Base_Version = 1;
    public static final String Table_Name = "table";

    public static final String NAME_PRODUCT = "name_product";


}
```

Shorted xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Edit_Delete_Product"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    >

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view_edit_delete_product"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        >
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_edit_del_product"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            android:paddingStart="4dp"
            android:paddingEnd="4dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="55dp"
            />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Shorted version of Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.things">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <provider
            android:name="br.com.mauker.materialsearchview.db.HistoryProvider"
            android:authorities="br.com.mauker.materialsearchview.searchhistorydatabase"
            android:exported="false"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"
            android:syncable="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Edit_Delete_Product"
            android:label="@string/toolbar_edit_del_pr" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Add_Product"
            android:label="@string/action_bar_name_add" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/action_bar_name_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set an OnQueryTextListener on your SearchView.

In onQueryTextChange will be called everytime the user enters a character in the SearchView

there you can filter the list you got from your Databse and submit the filtered list to your recyclerView adapter.

Something like this. Example is in Kotlin.

```
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            //perform your filtering here
            return false
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I had integrated the below search view in various projects. All you need is there.

https://github.com/Mauker1/MaterialSearchView

One of my project:

https://bitbucket.org/codesteam/news_template/src/master/

Let's understand first how it works, then you can write with your own way by downloading the source or just using Gradle dependency.

From my given project I first downloaded the source code and put all the files in the path:

/app/src/main/java/com/materialsearchview

Let's start with **SearchViewManager** It is a file that contains MaterialSearchView instance, so by creating SearchViewManager instance from any activity I can instantiate search view and get access to public members of it so I can do what I need to do. For example, I used it in my MainActivity, to make SearchViewManager functional bellow lines of code is necessary

MainActivity.java

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            searchViewManager = SearchViewManager.getInstance(this);
            searchViewManager.create();
            searchViewManager.addParrent((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.searchViewContainer));
}

protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        searchViewManager.addParrent(searchViewContainer);
            searchViewManager.setSearchItemClickListner(this);
            searchViewManager.getSearchView().activityResumed();
    }

@Override
protected void onPause() {
        searchViewManager.removeParrent();
}

@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        searchViewManager.getSearchView().clearSuggestions();

    }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (searchViewManager.getSearchView().isOpen()) {
        // Close the search on the back button press.
        searchViewManager.getSearchView().closeSearch();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(SearchItem searchItem) {
    if (searchItem != null){
        
    }
}
```

Now in activity_main.xml I have bellow container in where I injected the search view which I created by using SearchViewManager

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/searchViewContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>
```

So again, I create an instance of SearchViewManager inside of the onCreate function of my activity then I call searchViewManager.create(); which creates the MaterialSearchView then I call searchViewManager.addParrent((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.searchViewContainer)); and pass the container in where the created search view will showed. and onResume function of my activity I attached searchViewManager.setSearchItemClickListner(this); so my activity will trigger an event if user search using search view and click on an Item because I Implemented  OnSearchItemClick

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnSearchItemClick {
}
```

Now in the manifest file, I used appId for auth of the content provider so it makes searchview manager portable and it will have a different signature if the user installs more then one app which contains the same code for search view.

```
// in  mainifest file
<provider
            android:name="com.materialsearchview.db.HistoryProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.searchhistorydatabase"
            android:exported="false"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"
            android:syncable="true"/> 

// in HistoryContract.java 

private static String initAuthority() {
        String authority = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".searchhistorydatabase";
        return authority;
    }
```

or you can write how the doc says to create a MsvAuthority.java and hard code the auth string and use it where it needed and use the same string in your manifest file, just follow how doc says.

in that case, it will be like this

```
public class MsvAuthority {
    public static final String CONTENT_AUTHORITY = "com.myapp.searchhistorydatabase";
}
public class HistoryContract {

    public static final String CONTENT_AUTHORITY = MsvAuthority.CONTENT_AUTHORITY;
}

 <provider
            android:name="com.materialsearchview.db.HistoryProvider"
            android:authorities="com.myapp.searchhistorydatabase.searchhistorydatabase"
            android:exported="false"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"
            android:syncable="true"/>
```

Now, advice for you: I wrote and updated this search view code while I am coding for the entire project, so at first get a clear view what they are saying (gitHub readme.md) then understand my concept how I implemented it for my own needs, then start just write a small project in where you will implement search view successfully with minimal code.

If you like the search view manager concept then start to implement it in your own way, you can take help by seeing my code.

If you have a question please feel free to ask me, I will assist you until you finish search view successfully :D

Comment: Your sollutions is very usefull and thanks for it, but I still don`t now how to connect all this material searchview with recycler_adapter. In my opinion I should have method in recyler_adapter then invoke it from searchview(that is in Mainactivity) right?

Comment: @MatLL, yes it is a bit hard to set up, for me it took significant time to integrate in my first project. I am confident you can do it, just follow the setup instruction. After a successful setup, you will gain a sound knowledge of content providers. If you need help just hit me with question where you stuck.

Comment: I have made all this things from setup. You said, you used it in different projects. Have you used it with sql database and recyclerview?
I don't know what to do now. Should I focus for sollution about filtering recyclerview without any array (that is how would like to resolve) or I should use arraylist? But my recycler_adapter also grab data from cursor, not from arraylist. 
Surely I must have two arraylist one with all items and second to show "matching" words. (Connect one of them to cursor, so that cursor fill the arraylist??)

Comment: I also tried something like this in Mainactivity:
searchView.getAdapter().bindView( view, getApplicationContext(), cursor);
Maybe my searchview should call method from Recycler_adapter and recycler_adapter must extends filterable?
In simply words I want to bind searchview --> recyclerview  (recycler_adapter) --> sql database.   
Two comments beacuse one is too long...

Comment: here is one of my projects, If you have accessing problems let me know.  https://bitbucket.org/codesteam/news_template/src/master/

Comment: from the above link go to main activity there you will find SearchViewManager, You can omit code related RenderManager with SerchViewManager, render manager trigger search view manager when a user surfing in the application and got a new notification from the server. Yes, I used both SQL lite and recycle view in the application. but my search view located on the top of the screen. there is a special item in the recycle view name search a news, if the user clicks on that item, I instantly take recycle view in-focus state.

Comment: I have edited my post, put my code. Read and tried your sollution but something goes wrong, maybe it is to complicated for me.
If something is missing let me know, also resign of materialsearchview, how it is now, is enough. What would you do, if you were me.?

Comment: let me assist you to answer the question step by step. please also provide codes inside AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Ok. I added shorted version of manifest, if it isn't work, I will add full version, but in full version there isn't anything special just a few class more... Also added provider with materialsearchview  but this thing doesn't change anything. Ok that's all, I am waiting for your answer.

Comment: You said I can use gradle implementation  or download source code.
1. If I used gradle implementation " implementation 'br.com.mauker.materialsearchview:materialsearchview:1.2.3'" I have an error cannot find SearchViewManager class in MainActivity.
2.If I got it right I can download your all code  or I require  only this code that is located in your materialsearchview folder  and put to "/app/src/main/java/com/materialsearchview

Comment: 3. Xml file shouldn't have searchview or br.com.mauker.materialsearchview insetad of Linear Layout with id searchviewcontainer like is it now. If I understand it java creates dynamically searchview on linearlayout box

Comment: 1. SearchViewManager is created by because I was in need of instantiate MaterialSearchView only once for my entire app lifecycle when it runs and users go from one activity to another activity, you will see SearchViewManager is a  class that follows singleton design pattern. yes, you can use Gradle implementation and create a search view manager to manage Material Search View for your purpose.

Comment: 2. Main reason for downloading source codet is I need to pass and store some specific data to Material Search View, beacaue when user search an item I had to show item icon, title , short description as a search list item, I also had to pass search item id which I got from server through the rest api call , if you go to the db folder and investigate all those class inside that folder you will see, app/src/main/java/com/materialsearchview/db/SearchItem.java, off course if you need to download source code to full-fill your needs go ahed.

Comment: 3. yes it attached created search view into search view container by using addParrent method of SearchViewManager.

Comment: When I start enter letters, android gives me errors. E/ActivityThread failed to find provider info for: br.com.mauker.materialsearchview.defaultsearchhistorydatabase. I tried to change String in MsvActivity to com.example.things or com.example.things.searchhistorydatabase or write 'something' also remember to change it in manifest, in provider in attribute authorities, but still not working. Also added sth like this https://github.com/Mauker1/MaterialSearchView/issues/12

Comment: try to compare between https://bitbucket.org/codesteam/news_template/src/master/app/src/main/java/com/materialsearchview/db/HistoryContract.java  and https://github.com/Mauker1/MaterialSearchView/blob/master/app/src/main/java/br/com/mauker/MsvAuthority.java

Comment: Once I also got the same error, as far as I remember I solve it by deleting the defaultsearchhistorydatabase from HistoryContract.java and added my own auth string what I gave for my provider in the AndroidManifest.xml which is android: :authorities="${applicationId}.searchhistorydatabase"  in here I used application id for diffrent purpose you can use a string, but remember it should be same in every occurence where it need to be. let me know if it solve your problem

Comment: Yes, solved it :D. I am implementing materialsearchview using gradle so I had to copy String authority from HistoryContract and then set the same in manifest and MsvActivity.class

Comment: Now, I don't know, what to do, Your code is expanded. I think I should have sth filter logic. But where I should use it? In RecyclerView_Adapter.class or in MainActivity? 

CursorSearchAdapter from mauker I should implement somewhere (call some methods on it)  or it is  enough if it is located in gradle files?
If I looked good you used two ArrayLists? Write data from sql database to one of them and  if the user enter some letters then screen show us second array with matching words?

Comment: Just only EntryDao.class should interest me? 
Is there anywhere (class or)  anything  else in your project that should I  take into account ?

Comment: EntryDao.class is doing 2 things first it stores data into my project SQLite database for my future use (those data I downloaded from the server) then it passes some specific and formatted data (SearchItem) to MaterialSearchView for a user to search those items. Yes you can look EntryDao.class and it's functional behaviour, but remember I did not wrote whole class and it's functionality at once, so I will advise you that start from a point then move forward according to your needs. It's realy good to hear that your search view is working fine.

Comment: Now when I enter some letters, nothing is changing, all elements are displayed like when activity is in normal state. I have got class like your SearchItem.class Should I connect it with searchviewmanager.class or create an array in Recyler_Adapter class or in MainActivity? What to do when the array will be created?